# Unable to remove Bootstrap Dependency From Angular 13

Tags: angular, npm

I have removed all the bootstrap references from package.json and styles but still I am getting the error -
no such file or directory, lstat 'angular-src\node_modules\bootstrap'.
I checked the logs the error is coming from @angular-devkit/build-angular(13.3.5).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Later I found that there are references of bootstrap present in angular.json. I removed those references from angular.json and built the solution again. Working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Were you serving the application while you did these steps?

**If you did:**

Stop the application in the terminal with:

`Ctrl + C`

And serve the application again with:

`ng serve`

Comment: not working....

Comment: Were you serving the application while you did these steps? If yes, please stop (ctrl. + c in terminal) the compilation and serve the application again with ng serve

Comment: working fine now..removed the references of bootstrap from angular.json also

Comment: Could you mark my solution as accepted? I edited it so other people can also see the solution :)

Comment: @SvenMärki this is not the solution... as the OP reported, the solution was to remove the ref from the angular.json file